# Перевод темы WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Перевожу шаблон WP Rentals на русский язык, столкнулся с некоторыми проблемами.
Не получается перевести отзывы.
Нужно чтобы в зависимости от цифры менялось окончание слова: 3 отзыва, 1 отзыв и тд. Сейчас же сделано просто: 1 Reviews . В каком файле это правится по стандарту?

Comment: https://truemisha.ru/blog/wordpress/translations.html

Answer (score 1):

http://dimox.name/plural-form-of-nouns/

Когда нужен текст вида 21 комментарий.

В файле functions.php темы вставляем функцию:

```
function plural_form($number, $after) {
  $cases = array (2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2);
  echo $number.' '.$after[ ($number%100>4 && $number%100<20)? 2: $cases[min($number%10, 5)] ];
}
```

А в то место, где нужно выводить текст о количестве комментов, вставляем такой код:

```
<?php
plural_form(
  get_comments_number(),
  /* варианты написания для количества 1, 2 и 5 */
  array('комментарий','комментария','комментариев')
);
?>
```